# Putting <iframe></iframe> tag onto a Mediawiki page

Tags: iframe, mediawiki

I have set Mediawiki up and am trying to imbed the code:

```
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work. All that happens is the code appears on the bottom of the page, rather than the wikipedia page.
I have already made 3 edits to the Mediawiki LocalSettings.php file. they were

```
$wgAllowIframes = true;
$wgBreakFrames = false;
$wgEditPageFrameOptions = 'SAMEORIGIN';
```

But it still doesn;t work.
Does anybody have any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: How did you try? Did you use JavaScript or wikitext?

Comment: To my knowledge, iframe is html. And wikitext is only for formatting.

Comment: Not necessarily. Wikitext does include HTML. By default some HTML tags are allowed, such as `<div>` and `<span>`, while others will be escaped and displayed as plain text. There are extensions that allows you to add those to a page using wikitext, e.g. [this one](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IframePage).

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are there to allow or deny your wiki from being embedded as an iframe in another site.

If you want to use iframes in your wiki you need to add an extension:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IframeTag